# How to redirect my sudomains webspace to the actual subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect https://example.com/sub/index.php to https://sub.example.com/index.php.

As you can tell, the subdomains webspace is in the actual domain webspace; this leads to duplicate content.

I already tried this:

1. Adding javascript to index.php's head:

   ```html
   <script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='https://example.com/sub/index.php';</script>
   ```

   But this creates an infinte loop.
2. Adding .htaccess to /sub/ directory:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.example.com/index.php$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

   But this makes it impossible to create other files in /sub/ because it always redirects you to index.php

What would be the best way to solve this if I also want to create other files in /sub/ which always redirect to the subdomain version?

Comment: Is the subdirectory structure identical to that of the subdomain?  I.e. will `http://sub.example.com/path/to/my/file.php` redirect to `http://example.com/sub/path/to/my/file.php`?

Comment: @bluemoon6790 it should be the other way around but yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following placed at the root of your site should redirect anything that hits `example.com/sub` to `sub.example.com`.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

You can test it at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ if you need to tweak those rules.